# Mongo Aggregation : $group and $project array to object for counts

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents like:

```
{
    "platform":"android",
    "install_date":20151029
}
```

1. platform - can have one value from [android|ios|kindle|facebook ] .
2. install_date - there are many install_dates

There are also many fields.

**Aim** : I am calculating installs per platform on particular date.

So I am using group by in aggregation framework and make counts by platform. Document should look like like:

```
{
  "install_date":20151029,
  "platform" : {
   "android":1000,
   "ios": 2000,
   "facebook":1500
  }
}
```

---

I have done like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: { platform: "$platform",install_date:"$install_date"},  
            count: { "$sum": 1 } 
        }
  },
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: { install_date:"$_id.install_date"},
          platform: { $push :  {platform :"$_id.platform", count:"$count" } }  
      }
  },
  { 
     $project : { _id: 0, install_date: "$_id.install_date", platform: 1 } 
  }     
])
```

which Gives document like:

```
{
    "platform": [
        {
            "platform": "facebook",
            "count": 1500
        },
        {
            "platform": "ios",
            "count": 2000
        },
        {
            "platform": "android",
            "count": 1000
        }
    ],
    "install_date": 20151027
}
```

**Problem:**

Projecting array to single object as "platform"

Comment: Are you saying you have a "string" separateed by slashes `/`? Or are these just possible values of that "platform" field? It's a really unlcear way to present that. Secondly, the basic question of "zero" data has been asked many times before here, so have you looked? You should not be attempting to make a database return information that does not exist. Also please be clear about the result goal here. I understand you are asking for all platforms per date, but how many dates exactly and what is the end purpose. All of that makes it easier to present a correct response.

Comment: @BlakesSeven : These are possible values. There any many dates. It should group by date and give devices installed on that date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With MongoDb 3.4 and newer, you can leverage the use of [**`$arrayToObject`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) operator to get the desired result. You would need to run the following aggregate pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {  
            "date": "$install_date",  
            "platform": { "$toLower": "$platform" }
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.date",
        "counts": {
            "$push": {
                "k": "$_id.platform",
                "v": "$count"
            }
        }
    } },
    {  "$addFields": {
        "install_date": "$_id", 
        "platform": { "$arrayToObject": "$counts" }
    }  },
    { "$project": { "counts": 0, "_id": 0 } } 
])
```

---

For older versions, take advantage of the [**`$cond`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) operator in the [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) pipeline step to evaluate the counts based on the platform field value, something like the following:

```
db.collection.aggregate([    
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$install_date",             
        "android_count": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$platform", "android" ] }, 1, 0 ]
            }
        },
        "ios_count": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$platform", "ios" ] }, 1, 0 ]
            }
        },
        "facebook_count": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$platform", "facebook" ] }, 1, 0 ]
            }
        },
        "kindle_count": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$platform", "kindle" ] }, 1, 0 ]
            }
        } 
    } },
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0, "install_date": "$_id",            
        "platform": {
            "android": "$android_count",
            "ios": "$ios_count",
            "facebook": "$facebook_count",
            "kindle": "$kindle_count"
        }
    } }
])
```

In the above, [**`$cond`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) takes a logical condition as it's first argument (if) and then returns the second argument where the evaluation is true (then) or the third argument where false (else). This makes true/false returns into 1 and 0 to feed to `$sum` respectively.

So for example, if `{ "$eq": [ "$platform", "facebook" ] },`  is true then the expression will evaluate to `{ $sum: 1 }` else it will be `{ $sum: 0 }`

Comment: what the 1,0 do at the end of each condition?

Comment: `$cond` takes a logical condition as it's first argument `(if)` and then returns the second argument where the evaluation is true (then) or the third argument where false (else). This makes true/false returns into 1 and 0 to feed to `$sum` respectively. So fo example, if `{ "$eq": [ "$platform", "facebook" ] }, ` is true then the expression will evaluate to `{ $sum: 1 }` else it will be `{ $sum: 0 }`